# How to add swipe tab feature with existing FragmentTabHost?

Tags: android

I am using FragmentTabHost in my app. It is working perfectly well. I have two tabs, which are opened by clicking on the top. Now, I want to add swipe feature in this. I am wondering whether I should use a different approach for the same.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.shiza.callhistorycontrol;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        Setting up a toolbar for the navigation purpose.

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        toolbar.setTitle(" Call History Control");
        toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//        The fragments management is done here

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("HOME"),
                Home.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("ABOUT APP"),
                Home.class, null);


    }

}
```

main xml:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- the app bar customized-->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Please provide me any links or any suggestions?

Comment: are you using an adapter?

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie No I am not using any adapter

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that I wrote creates `TabHost` with swipe feature:

**First the main fragment that holds the adapter and add tabs with (two childes fragments).**

```
public  class MyFragment extends Fragment
{

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    public MyFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle instance)
    {
        super.onCreate(instance);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mTabHost = (TabHost) v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getActivity(), mTabHost, mViewPager);

// Here we load the content for each tab.

        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("HOME"), FirstPage.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("HOME"), SecondPage.class, null);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
    {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final TabHost mTabHost;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo
        {
            private final String tag;
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args)
            {
                tag = _tag;
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory
        {
            private final Context mContext;

            public DummyTabFactory(Context context)
            {
                mContext = context;
            }

            public View createTabContent(String tag)
            {
                View v = new View(mContext);
                v.setMinimumWidth(0);
                v.setMinimumHeight(0);
                return v;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager)
        {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mTabHost = tabHost;
            mViewPager = pager;
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args)
        {
            tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
            String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);

            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);

        }

        public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
        {
            int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
        {
        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
            // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
            // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
            // The jerk.
            // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
            // ViewPager.
            TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
            int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
        }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
        {
        }
    }
```

Then create another two fragments that represent each tab and call them:

**FirstPage**

**SecondPage**

link those to `xml` files, call `new MyFragment` and you are good to go.

Comment: Fair and quick solution

Comment: @ahmad-alsanie i get this error after adding your adapter in new class and addtab to adapter

Comment: No tab known for tag fragmentb