# TabActivity error in Android

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to use tabactivity but I can't seem to make it work. I tried to extend the MainActivity to TabActivity but it seems to be deprecated.

The code I am using right now is as follows:

```
package jdexamples.app13_exploringtabs;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // tabhost


        TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("First").setContent(new Intent(this  ,first.class )));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("Second").setContent(new Intent(this , second.class )));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("third").setIndicator("Third").setContent(new Intent(this, third.class)));
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }


}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this ?

I tried suggestions from [Android Maps within TabHost. getTabHost() return error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967315/android-maps-within-tabhost-gettabhost-return-error) but when I try to launch the application on the emulator, it always crashes.

**The logcat is as follows:**

```
10-16 22:09:01.375  11571-11571/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-16 22:09:01.375  11571-11571/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling JIT
10-16 22:09:01.377  11571-11571/? I/art﹕ JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
10-16 22:09:01.537  11571-11571/jdexamples.app13_exploringtabs W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/jdexamples.app13_exploringtabs-2/lib/x86
10-16 22:09:01.565  11571-11571/jdexamples.app13_exploringtabs D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-16 22:09:01.565  11571-11571/jdexamples.app13_exploringtabs E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: jdexamples.app13_exploringtabs, PID: 11571
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jdexamples.app13_exploringtabs/jdexamples.app13_exploringtabs.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TabHost.setup()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TabHost.setup()' on a null object reference
            at jdexamples.app13_exploringtabs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-16 22:09:05.029  11571-11571/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 11571 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please show your logcat

Comment: why have you commented `setContentView()`

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi Probably comment out

Comment: The best way currently is to use a TabLayout, look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698756/remove-line-break-in-tablayout/32547335#32547335

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Of all Enable

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

**TabActivity** This class was deprecated in API level 13.
New applications should use Fragments instead of this class; to continue to run on older devices, you can use the v4 support library .

**Bad Approach**

Using *deprecated* code .

Switch to **FragmentActivity Or AppCompatActivity**

Have a look here

1. [How to add swipe tab feature with existing FragmentTabHost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624317/how-to-add-swipe-tab-feature-with-existing-fragmenttabhost)
2. [Android app keeps crashing with tabhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059519/android-app-keeps-crashing-with-tabhost)

> http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setup(android.app.LocalActivityManager)

Comment: You got why i was asking for the comment :). Probably because of that there is this `NullPointerException`

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi Good observation .

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use PagerSlidingTabs.
Check this link [here](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

By using above library you can swipe pages using ViewPager.
You can see working example on Play Store [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample).
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for recommending that. I used that and looks really good. However, I had problems adding any information on the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Android has now provided new way to implement tabs in your app which are really simple to use...

First you have to add a dependency to your project:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

After that you have to declare your tabLayout in your activity's xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFC107"
            app:tabMinWidth="30dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Now in your activity class do something like this:

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(your_view_pager);
```